# web3 - Can I call a library function without a contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, library

I have a library which contains a function concat - it can merge two bytes. I have deployed a contract which uses that library and it works. I would like to make a simple bytes builder on my website. Do I need to deploy a special contract BytesBuilder or can I simply call the already deployed library and call lib.concat somehow?

Comment: I believe that if the function is `public` in the library then it is also `public` in the contract, and therefore you can call it via the contract. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, my contract communicates with library with success. My question was can I exclude the contract and just call the library which has already been deployed and call function to build bytes, or have I to deploy another contract, add some more functions for builder and deploy again.

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstanding, sorry. Let me explain. 

I can't use my contract I already have deployed because it implements the library only for it's internal use: I call the function with bytes put as parameter and it grabs it and splits to necessary chunks and performs other work with them - it works perfectly.

Then I found out I could make an external bytes builder generator on my website. The library has ready to go functions to merge bytes, but the contract doesn't, it only reads and parses. I was thinking if I could still use that library to make a builder.

Comment: So there is no misunderstanding here. As I stated in my first comment - if the function is public in the library, then you can call it via the contract which you have already deployed. Otherwise, you'd need to expose it in a new contract (either by declaring it public this time, or by providing a public function in the new contract, which will call the internal function in the library).

Comment: By the way, for an "external bytes builder generator on my website", you don't need neither a contract nor a library (i.e., you don't need anything on the blockchain). You can get it done with a simple usage of `web3.utils`. It will also work much faster (no RPC involved).

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks very much for your reply, your support was very helpful for me.

Comment: np!!!!!!!!!!!!!